# Recursive definitions, How it is done?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, recursion

I read that recursive definitions, refer to the definition of a function in that function body, cannot be done in $\lambda$-calculus, but recursion can be achieved by using $Y$ combinator.

As I know, nominal logic is the theory of handling bindings. So wondering how it handles recursive definition  of functions? Does it still use combinators as it is done in $\lambda$-calculus? [nominal logic](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/nomlfo/nomlfo-draft.pdf)

I think higher-order abstract syntax takes the same approach taken by $\lambda$-calculus, since it is based on $\lambda$-calculus. am I right?

If there is a good technique for handling recursive definition different than using a combinator as mentioned above, Please point it out. I want to know.
What is the common  way to handle recursion?

Could anyone clarify these to me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you realize that the $Y$ combinator can be defined in $\lambda$-calculus as $Y = \lambda f . (\lambda x . f (x x)) (\lambda x . f (x x))$?

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "handle recursive definitions"? How to express them? How to compute fixed points? Please be more specific.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I know that $Y$ combinator can be defined and used to implement recursion in $\lambda$-calculus. I am asking that is this the case for nominal logic? How recursion defined in nominal logic? Does it use $Y$ Combinator as well?

Comment: In that case it would be helpful if you give a reference to a specific nominal logic as you could have in mind any number of variants.

Comment: @AndrejBauer added the paper about nominal logic.

Comment: You usually don't have to resort to Y combinator to implement recursion.  See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2222637/97045

Comment: Ok, so you are referring to Andy Pitt's nominal logic. Please note that this is *not* a calculus of functions, i.e., it's not comparable to $\lambda$-calculus in a direct way. Instead it's a kind of non-standard set theory. As such it does not support unrestricted recursion. But there is [nominal domain theory](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-751.pdf), which does, you can look that up.

Comment: @DanielV: you should mention that the solution you are referring to only gives primitive recursion, whereas the $Y$ combinator gives unrestricted recursion.